# WPF - Shared keyborad Shortcut keys are not working if one disabled

Tags: wpf

I have two short cut keys for buttons starting with "U" ( 'U' & another one with 'UA') Which is working fine if both the buttons are in enabled mode.

If the first button ('U' short cut) is disabled then it is not recognizing the 'UI' shortcut Key (button for this is enabled)

Any idea how to resolve this?